# Implementing JS arithmetic operators in node.js C++ addon

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

Is it possible to implement arithmetic operators in a node.js C++ addon ?

So if `myclass` is a JS object wrapped from a c++ class, can I implement the javascript "+"  operator in a wrapped C++ function's class, so that the following code would work ?

```
var a = new myclass();
var b = new myclass();
var c = a + b;
```

It would permit a more elegant handling of arithmetic operations on appropriate objects (if *myclass* represents a vector or matrix class for example). For now, the only solution is to declare a normal function to handle the operators, like :

```
var c=a.add(b);
```

But it is not nice. I hope someone with knowledge of v8 internals can answer this.

Comment: To what end? I'm not entirely sure I understand. It's possible you're just asking "can I define `+` for two objects of type `myclass`", to which the answer is _yes, C++ supports operator overloading_.

Comment: I highly doubt this is possible. However, the operator overloading isn't the magic. The magic is in method overloading by type, which would be much more useful. Sadly, I doubt that would be possible either.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm not speaking about operator overloading in C++ of course but to implement in the c++ addon class the javascript + operator. The question makes sense since i'm trying to implement some matrix class c++ side and have their corresponding javascript objects behave in a natural way. Because I see no better way of doing it, I will just implement functions .add(object), .substract(object), etc.

Comment: No, this isn’t possible. (Please don’t do it, either. Half the fun of JavaScript is reasonable expectations!)

Comment: As stated, not possible. Such a change would have to be internal to the Javascript engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the behavior of the `+` operator is not exposed for modification.

The ECMA-262 spec defining JavaScript defines the `+` operator as either adding two numbers, or concatenating two strings. To do this, implementations call `.toString()` and/or `.valueOf()` on the object, and then perform concatenation or addition. Nothing about the operator itself is ever exposed to the implementation C++ code. The C++ code can only effect the string/value returned for processing.